# ImageField is not uploading to specified directory

Tags: django, django-models, imagefield

I have been googling this for an ours and can't find the solution.
When I use admin panel, image is loading to the directory that is needed. But when I create post from the frontend, the image is just loading to the main directory, which is media. I now that I it will work if I use django forms and createview, but I need adding a post with a function like I did. I think this problem might happen, because ImageField needs validating. But I don't know how to validate it outside the django forms context.

I have model Posts with ImageField image and upload_to option:

```
class Posts(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="posts/%Y/%m/%d", null=True,blank=True)
```

then in views.py the function, that adds new post:

```
@login_required
def add_post(request):
        
    if request.method == 'POST':

        title = request.POST.get('title')
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        
        upload_file = request.FILES['image']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()

        image = fs.save(upload_file.name, upload_file)
        
        post = Posts(title=title, content=content, image= image)
        post.author = request.user
                
        post.save()

        from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

        #return redirect(post.get_absolute_url())
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

    return render(request ,'users/user-detail2.html')
```

and the which displays the form:

```
<form action="{% url 'add_post' %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Share Your Mood</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body custom-scroll">
        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Post title" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body custom-scroll">
        <input type="file" id="image" name="image" rows="5" class="form-control">
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body custom-scroll">
        <textarea name="content" class="share-field-big custom-scroll" placeholder="Say Something"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="post-share-btn" data-dismiss="modal">cancel</button>
        
        <input type="submit" value="Post" class="post-share-btn">
    </div>    
</form>
```

settings.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

main urls.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:

    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use **`FileSystemStorage`** class here. Just save the file as below

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect


@login_required
def add_post(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.POST.get('title')
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        upload_file = request.FILES['image']
        post = Posts(title=title, content=content, image=upload_file, author=request.user)
        post.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    return render(request, 'users/user-detail2.html')
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what could be causing this

Try adding this to your model

```
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage

media = FileSystemStorage(location='/media/posts/%Y/%m/%d')
```